# How does Angular find the ng-template to render in case of duplicates?

Tags: angular

So my question comes from copy pasting an `ngIf-else` in another place of the same file. I undestand this is not particular to `else` and its probably general angular behavior.

I have 2 `ng-templates` both named `isCompany` and the code seems to work fine.

Code example:

```
 a
  ng-container(*ngIf='user.kind === "user"; else isCompany')
   span Skillsheet
  ng-template(#isCompany="")
   span Technologies we Use

 a
  ng-container(*ngIf='user.kind === "user"; else isCompany')
   span Want to Work
  ng-template(#isCompany="")
   span Want to Hire
```

My questions are:

- How does angular "scan" the DOM to find which `ng-template` to
     render?
- Is there a chance that those 2 will be mixed up at one
     point?

I guess giving different identifiers on the templates just solves this, but my question is about the behavior here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chance that `ng-template`s with the same name will get mixed. Not always but some times, so you better not use 2 templates with the same name it.

Yeah, I don't know what I expected, I was just curious to find this out.